# javascript document.getElementById("device") doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Why does `alert(p1)` show `null`?

http://pastebin.com/VAKwwEge

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/product.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Device:<select id="device" name="device" style="width:250px;"> </select>                      Line:<select id="line" name="line" style="width:250px;"> </select>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = load();
function load() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("device");
    var l1 = document.getElementById("line");
    alert(p1);
    alert(l1);
}
```

Comment: mine [worked](http://jsfiddle.net/CruhJ/)

Comment: You're wrong. It doesn't show null: http://jsfiddle.net/5DjuW/

Comment: Guys, buy default jsfiddle wraps the call into the `onLoad` event of the library (by default MooTools) . You should choose `no wrap (head)` in the left panel to reproduce the issue

Comment: The jsfiddle comments posted are **not valid** because they are set to execute the given JavaScript during the mootools `onLoad` event. There's no reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
window.onload = load();
```

To read the following:

```
window.onload = load;
```

Note the difference, the first example will **invoke** the `load()` function, and assign its return value to `window.onload`, which of course will be `undefined`.

The second example will assign the function itself to `window.onload`, which is what you want, and will alert `[object HTMLSelectElement]` (in Firefox anyways).

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
function load() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("device");
    var l1 = document.getElementById("line");
    alert(p1);
    alert(l1);
}
window.onload = load;
```

The assignment to onload needs to be a function reference, not the execution of the function (no parens).

Somewhat simpler would be using an anonymous function like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("device");
    var l1 = document.getElementById("line");
    alert(p1);
    alert(l1);
}
```

Comment: Your second point, *The assignment to onload needs to be after the definition of the function* is not true, but the rest of your answer is sound.

Comment: Second point removed.  Example using anonymous function added.